# Adding two values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to add two values in one single statement and I'm currently at a loss as to how to go about this, it should be simple enough here are my statements:

```
 SELECT COUNT(UserModified) as SecondTally
 FROM JobAgents 
 WHERE UserModified = 1
```

The value above is then subtracted from this value below.

```
 SELECT SUM(EmailsSent) as FirstTally
 FROM JobAgentEmails
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '7/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '7/31/2012 11:59:59 PM'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be to simply combine the results with two sub-queries, which could either be stored in variables, or simply combined in a single query as shown below:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(EmailsSent) as FirstTally
   FROM JobAgentEmails
   WHERE Date BETWEEN '7/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '7/31/2012 11:59:59 PM')
- (SELECT COUNT(UserModified) as SecondTally
   FROM JobAgents 
   WHERE UserModified = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a cross join get bring the values together:

```
select jae.FirstTallyl - ja.SecondTally
from (SELECT COUNT(UserModified) as SecondTally
      FROM JobAgents
      WHERE UserModified = 1
     ) ja cross join
     (SELECT SUM(EmailsSent) as FirstTally
      FROM JobAgentEmails
      WHERE Date BETWEEN '7/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '7/31/2012 11:59:59 PM'  
    ) jae
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
DECLARE @FirstTally int;
DECLARE @SecondTally int;

SELECT @SecondTally = COUNT(UserModified) 
 FROM JobAgents 
 WHERE UserModified = 1

 SELECT @FirstTally = SUM(EmailsSent) 
 FROM JobAgentEmails
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '7/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '7/31/2012 11:59:59 PM'


SELECT @FirstTalley - @SecondTalley AS Result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select 
 (SELECT SUM(EmailsSent) as FirstTally
 FROM JobAgentEmails
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '7/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '7/31/2012 11:59:59 PM')
 -

 (SELECT COUNT(UserModified) as SecondTally
 FROM JobAgents 
 WHERE UserModified = 1)

 AS 'result';
```